# PowerShell switch statement with conditionals

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

How to have conditionals in a PowerShell `switch` statement? This code below returns `0` when it should return `1000`.

```
$UsedSpaceMB = 8500

switch ($UsedSpaceMB) {
    ($UsedSpaceMB -gt 15000) { $FreeSpace = 2000 }
    ($UsedSpaceMB -in 8000..15000 ) { $FreeSpace = 1000 }
    ($UsedSpaceMB -in 1700..8000 ) { $FreeSpace = 500 }
    ($UsedSpaceMB -in 1000..1700 ) { $FreeSpace = 200 }
    ($UsedSpaceMB -in 800..1000 ) { $FreeSpace = 100 }
    ($UsedSpaceMB -lt 800 ) { $FreeSpace = 50 }
}
$FreeSpace
```

Comment: What is the use case for this code? Are you treating `-in` like some sort of betweens operator? If `$UsedSpaceMB` was a decimal this would not work. You would be better of I think using something like `$FreeSpace=switch($UsedSpaceMB){($_ -gt 15000){2000;break};($_ -gt 8000){1000;break}}`. So the first condition that succeeds returns your number and then we use break to be sure no other conditions will get met. `8000..15000` is making an array that you throw away right after making it. If this is run frequently that _could_ be a performance hindrance.

Comment: Thanks @Matt good points

Comment: As coded you were trying to compare a number with a boolean and it never matched. The code would have worked if you used a common idiom I've seen in several languages: `switch ($true){...`
In my opinion it makes more readable code than the {} expression syntax Persistent13 suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect for a switch.
Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) for the documentation.

```
$UsedSpaceMB = 8500

switch ($UsedSpaceMB) {
    {$_ -gt 15000} { $FreeSpace = 2000 }
    {$_ -in 8000..15000 } { $FreeSpace = 1000 }
    {$_ -in 1700..8000 } { $FreeSpace = 500 }
    {$_ -in 1000..1700 } { $FreeSpace = 200 }
    {$_ -in 800..1000 } { $FreeSpace = 100 }
    {$_ -lt 800 } { $FreeSpace = 50 }
}
$FreeSpace
```

Comment: Indeed, but I suggest adding `break` to each action script block, as a matter of habit. Otherwise the remaining branches are needlessly processed too (even though no other conditional would match in this case; in other cases, however, you may inadvertently trigger multiple actions).

Answer (score 1):

or you could use -contains

```
switch ($UsedSpaceMB) {
    {$_ -gt 15000} { $FreeSpace = 2000 }
    {8000..15000 -contains $_ } { $FreeSpace =1000 }
    {1700..8000 -contains $_} { $FreeSpace = 500 }
    {1000..1700 -contains $_ } { $FreeSpace = 200 }
    {800..1000 -contains $_ } { $FreeSpace = 100 }
    {$_ -lt 800 } { $FreeSpace = 50 }
}
$FreeSpace
```

Comment: A viable alternative if you need PSv2 support, To form good habits, I suggest terminating each action block with `break`, otherwise all other branches are processed as well (even if no other conditional matches in this case).